# Pass weak this pointer to its own function

Tags: c++, this, weak-ptr

Is it a good idea to have code like this:
Any pitfalls ?
Is it a better design to use shared this pointer ?

```
class X { 
   public:
   void foo();
   void bar2(const boost::weak_ptr<X>& x); 
};

void X::foo() {}
void X::bar2(const boost::weak_ptr<X>& x) {}
void foo() 
{
    const boost::shared_ptr<X> x = boost::make_shared<X>();
    boost::weak_ptr<X> weakX(x);
    x->bar2(weakX);
}

int 
main()
{
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is correct (It might have design issues, not revealed)

Comment: The obvious pitfall is this pointer being a regular pointer hence you may run into a situation where the object gets destroyed while a member function is running, take care. You may want to have a look at std::/boost:: enable_shared_from_this. Same pitfalls.

Answer (score 0):

If the argument passed in to the function is supposed to always be a `weak_ptr`-version of this you have a problem. There is nothing in the code enforcing this behaviour, so a user of your class could just as easily pass a weak_ptr to another object of `class X`.

If what you need is for `bar2` to be able to pass on a `shared_ptr` to `this`, a better solution is to use `std::enable_shared_from_this`

**Example**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Foo : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Foo> {
    Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::Foo\n"; }
    ~Foo() { std::cout << "Foo::~Foo\n"; } 
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> getFoo() { return shared_from_this(); }
};

int main() {
    Foo *f = new Foo;
    std::shared_ptr<Foo> pf1;

    {
        std::shared_ptr<Foo> pf2(f);
        pf1 = pf2->getFoo();  // shares ownership of object with pf2
    }

    std::cout << "pf2 is gone\n";   
}
```

**Output:**

```
Foo::Foo
pf2 is gone
Foo::~Foo
```

from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/enable_shared_from_this/shared_from_this